# Git branch rule policy name on merge or PR creation

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I want to enforce our branching model, so for that I want to restrict main branch but only allow branch names that start with `release/*` and `hotfix/*` (wildcards). How can I restrict git repos with this kind of rules in git merge and in pull request creations avoid installing third-parties addons, plugins or whatever?

Comment: If you control the Git server, you'd write a `pre-receive` [`git-hook`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to enforce your branch naming policy on the server side. That can disallow pushing new branches by name. I don't think there's a client-side hook to prevent the branches from being created locally, and I wouldn't recommend it. You mention Pull Requests; if this is on Github you can [protect branches](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches).

Comment: Do you want to restrict the naming of *all* branches to only release/ or hotfix/?

Comment: no, only for incoming branches that will merge into master

Comment: It this on Github, or another Git service, or are you running your own Git server? My recommendation would be to not fuss about the name of the branch, but to let the review process determine if the merge is valid; the important thing is to restrict direct commits to main.

Comment: this is on github. I agree with you but out business is very large and we need some strict rules to apply to our branching model, becuase we have a lack of expertiese and applying this kind of rules we want to mitigate some issues

Comment: Since you're on Github you can't use server-side Git hooks. Instead you'd use a [Github status check](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks) on your PRs to verify the branch name is correct. You can do this with a Github Action. Fortunately, someone has already done this for gitflow: [Check Branch Name](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/check-branch-name). I'd recommend more robust automatic status checks and review than simply the branch name.